# How to make handler of this local host on python?

Tags: python, html, jinja2, aiohttp

I have made a design for web-app with forms to input. Now i need to connect this forms with Python script. HTML design here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Port Scanner</title>
   <style>
       html {
           font-family: Verdana, "sans-serif";
       }

       body {
           min-height: 100vh;
           background: black no-repeat;
       }

       h1 {
           text-align: center;
           color: white;
           text-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.8);
       }

       #root {
           display: flex;
           flex-direction: column;
           align-items: center;
       }

       #messages {
           width: 70%;
       }

       .message {
           background-color: white;
           width: 100%;
           padding: 20px;
           border-radius: 10px;
           -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
           -moz-transition: 0.3s;
           transition: 0.3s;
           -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
           -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
           box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
           box-sizing: border-box;
           margin-bottom: 10px;
       }

       .message:hover {
           -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
           -moz-transition: 0.3s;
           transition: 0.3s;
           -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
           -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
           box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
       }

       .message__created {
           font-size: 12px;
           color: darkgrey;
           text-align: right;
       }

       .message__text {
           font-size: 20px;
           color: black;
           margin-top: 5px;
       }

       .message__ratings {
           display: flex;
           justify-content: space-between;
           font-size: 16px;
           font-weight: 400;
           margin-top: 5px;
       }

       .form {
           width: 70%;
           margin-bottom: 20px;

           display: flex;
           flex-direction: column;
           gap: 60px;
       }

       .form__button {
           text-align: center;
           margin-top: 150px;
           background-color: white;
           cursor: pointer;
       }

       .form__input, .form__button {
           box-sizing: border-box;
           width: 100%;
           font-size: 18px;
           outline: none;
           border: none;
           padding: 20px;
           border-radius: 15px;
           -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
           -moz-transition: 0.3s;
           transition: 0.3s;
           -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
           -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
           box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
       }

       .form__input:focus, .form__button:hover {
           -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
           -moz-transition: 0.3s;
           transition: 0.3s;
           -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
           -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
           box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
       }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
   <h1>Port Scanner</h1>
   <div id="root">
       <form class="form" onsubmit="sendMessage()">
           <input id="message_text" class="form__input" type="text"
                  placeholder="IP adress"/>
           <input id="message_text1" class="form__input" type="text"
                  placeholder="Range of ports"/>
           <button class="form__button" type="submit">Scan</button>
       </form>
       <div id="messages">

       </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="application/javascript">
   const sendMessage = () => {
       alert('Please wait for the scanning!');
   }
</script>
</html>
```

The main forms are "message_text1", "message_text2", button SCAN
How to transfer input data from localhost to Python Script?
Server library: aiohttp + jinja2
May be i can do it without Django/Flask?